# Ruby DataMapper: How can I do pagination?

Tags: ruby, pagination, datamapper

I am going to retrieve a list of objects.

```
get "/todoitems/?" do
  debugger
  todo = Todolist.all
  todo.to_json
end
```

Is there example that can retrieve page by page?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a gem [dm-pagination](http://rubygems.org/gems/dm-pagination) which provides pagination support for Datamapper

I also found [dm-paginator](http://rubygems.org/gems/dm-paginator)

Answer (score 0):

This should point you in the right direction:

http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/updating-showing-and-deleting-users#sec-pagination

Essentially, there's a gem called [will-paginate](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate) that takes care of sorting things in a page by page structure. There's an example included in the link